# Angular 2 throttle the amount of event or action gets fired off on a countrol

Tags: html, angular, typescript, optimization

In my application I have a inputbox where I search for the inputted value. I made it so it searches when the value inside the textbox has been changed.
The code is something like this:

```
<input id="searchTextField" [(ngModel)]="searchText" (ngModelChange)="SearchTextChange()" />
```

Back end Typescript code is like this :

```
private SearchTextChange(): void {
//do search 
}
```

Problem is that I realized this is highly inefficient, because I realized in most cases, when people type a word, I don't want it to search when people type the letter"a" or "app" when the intended word maybe "apple" or something like that.
Is there a way to limit the search amount gets triggered either in angular 2 or typescript?
so I either only perform a search max every 2 seconds, or only let angular fire off the event on the same control maximum 1 ngModelChange for every 2 seconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Template :

```
<input id="searchTextField" [(ngModel)]="searchText" />
```

Put this code in your component :

```
searchText:string;

ngAfterViewInit()
{
    let inputElm = document.getElementById("searchTextField");
    Observable.fromEvent(inputElm , 'keyup').debounceTime(200).subscribe( res => {
        // this will wait for 200ms and then this will called on input
        // call you api here like
        // this.get(searchText).subscribe();
    });
}
```

Comment: just curious what is the number based on? miliseconds?

Comment: another question is that so does this mean the observable would only be "active" every 2 seconds correct? Even if I have other event or things triggered from the input control? because from the code it looks like you are suggesting it to "lockdown" the input every 2 seconds so to speak.

Comment: nope , it will wait every 2 seconds while you are typing , just run the code and console the value , you will get the idea and you will be amazed.

Comment: I will just testing it now. Because right now my class is implementing OnInit, Would I have to change the implementation?
Also what library has the observable?
right now I am testing it in my program and my current libraries doesn't seem to contain Observable

Comment: import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

and implements OnInit , AfterViewInit