# Angular debounce only for user input

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, debouncing

I have a reactive form setup in Angular2. In a component i subscribe to value changes of a form control with debounce time of 500ms like:

```
myForm.get("myField").valueChanges.debounceTime(500).subscribe(...);
```

Is there a way to skip the debounce time if the value was changed by code, not by user? Or is there a way to split those 2 events?

Comment: You can use this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43123590/2349407 , it wont get called on value changed by programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where you set your value programatically, you can use `emitEvent:false`, where in the [**docs**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) is stated...

> If `emitEvent` is `true`, this change will cause a `valueChanges` event on the FormControl to be emitted. This defaults to `true`.

so setting this as `false` will not cause `valueChanges` to fire, so you can do the following if you are setting the value at some point:

```
this.myForm.get('myField').patchValue('my value', {emitEvent:false})
```

Comment: This is extremely important to keep in mind.  Especially when you have a form with multiple inputs that need to sync.  In a lot of scenarios, using `[(ngModel)]` two-way binding is fine, but for mine, I needed this.